# Prove there is no continous bijection $f:(0,1)\to S^1$ nor $g:[0,1]\to S^1$

Tags: general-topology

So I thought as follows: 
There is a continuous bijection from $[0,1)$ onto $S^1$ for example parametrization $r(x)=(\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$ so if bijective continuous $f:(0,1)\to S^1$ exits then there must be also some $h:(0,1)\to [0,1)$ such that $r \circ h = f$ so it is sufficient to prove that $h$ does not exists, what is easy.

For the second one $[0,1]$ is compact and $S^1$ is Hausdorff as $S^1\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ so if there exists a continuous bijection $g:[0,1]\to S^1$ then it must be homeomorphism, this cannot happened because $[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1$

Comment: Your argument works fine, indeed it's the standard argument used to prove such results. It remains to fill some details...

Comment: Note that a continuous bijection is not a homeomorphism; the existence of a continuous bijection $A \to B$ does not guarantee the existence of a continuous bijection $B \to A$.

Comment: Why would this $h$ exist???

Comment: @tomasz that's my question to the community over here. Question is "if my reasoning is all right?" in particular "is the idea that such an h has to exists is right".

Comment: @Kacper: this is all hypothethical, so I cannot say "no" -- if you assume falsehood, then everything can be proved. What we can judge is whether or not your reasoning for the existence of $h$ is sound. So what is your reasoning?

Comment: @tomasz I know that there need to be such a bijection like h since bijectivity is an equivalence relation so $[0,1)$ bijective to $S^1$ and $(0,1)$ bijective to $S^1$ gives us $(0,1)$ must be bijective to $[0,1)$. So let $h:(0,1)\to (0,1]$ be a bijection then clearly $r\circ h=f$ is bijection as well now we want f to be continous. Hence, since $r$ is continuous we need $h$ to be continuous as well. So in the end we need $h$ to be continuous bijection from $(0,1)\to [0,1)$. That's my reasoning is it all right?

Comment: I see now. No, it is not correct: the composition of a discontinuous function and a continuous function may be continuous. For example, any function composed with the constant function is continuous. Or if the domain of $r$ is discrete, then $r\circ h$ is continuous, even if $h$ is far from continuity (even if both are bijective!).

Comment: @tomasz so how would you prove the first statement i.e. that there is no continous bijection from $(0,1)$ onto $S^1$

Comment: @Kacper: I haven't given to it much thought. But I think it could be worth considering the images of $[1/n,1-1/n]$ by the hypothetical continuous bijection. Then by compactness, you can show (I think) that their union misses a point. But maybe there is an easier argument.

Comment: It's a little tough to make it work out just right, but I like this^ approach.

Comment: @tomasz ok, but why should the images of $[1/n, 1-1/n]$ be open in $S^1$ ?

Comment: @Randall I had an Idea how to use tomasz 's hint but my proof is not too rigorous i would say. Notice that since $f$ is continuous and injective and $I_n=[1/n, 1-1/n]$ is connected, then f must take $I_n$'s to closed arcs of $S^1$  (otherwise the same path would have to be "walked" twice what contradicts injectivity),  $f(I_n)\to f((0,1))=S^1$ as $n\to \infty$ whence $f(1/n)$ and $f(1-1/n)$ but since $f(I_n)$ is a closed arc for all n they must reach it so in the limit the end points of $f(I_n)$ overlap in consequence f is not injective.

Comment: @tomasz I could not put to names in one comment ;)

Comment: For the second, suppose $g : [0,1] \to \Bbb{S}^1$ cont. bijective. We have cont. bijective function $[0,1) \to \Bbb{S}^1\setminus \{p\} \approx \Bbb{R} \approx (0,1)$. Take $0 \in [0,1)$ and we have cont. bijective map from $(0,1) \to (0,1) \setminus \{a\}$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for the second case is completely correct. While the first case has a bug: even if you use the word "must", the existence of $h$ does not follow immediately from the hypothesis.

A proof of the first case can be done by using the [Theorem of invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) which asserts that a continuous inijective map from $\mathbb R^n$ to itself is injective.

Since $S^1$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, then any continuous bijection $f:(0,1)\to S^1$ is open, hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous and $f$ is a homeomorphism. But $S^1$ is not homeo to $(0,1)$ (the former is compact, the later no).

The proof of the invariance of domain in dimension 1 is particularly easy: let $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$ continuous an injective. For any $x\in (0,1)$, we want to prove that $f(x)$ is in the interior of the image of $f$. Since $(0,1)$ is connected and $f$ is continuous then $f(0,1)$ is connected, hence an interval I of $\mathbb R$. If $f(x)$ is not an interior point then $I$ is not an open interval, and w.l.o.g. we can suppose $I=[a,b)$ and $f(x)=a$. But now we easily contradict the injectivity of $f$ near $x$ by using that $[x,x+\varepsilon)$ and $(x-\varepsilon,x]$ both maps to intervals (because $f$ is continuous) of the type $[a,something)$.